# Why doesn't this base type extension work?

Tags: swift, generics, extension-methods

Trying to play with extensions, but am having issues getting the following to work:

```
let value = -13
abs(value)

extension Int {
    var abs:Int {
        return abs(self) // -> Cannot invoke 'abs' with an argument list of type '(Int)'
    }
}

value.abs
```

The compile error is weird, because it demonstrably runs the `abs()` function directly above with an `Int` as an argument. I've still got some light bulbs to trigger for generics I guess. Enlighten me.

Comment: Aha! Thanks both. I get it now. First person to edit their answer to show that I can scope the free function as `Swift.abs(self)` gets the `accept` :D

Comment: Aside, this is why I hate implicit self.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Swift compiler is confused that you use the `abs` variable as a function, which it cannot do. Now you could look at all the answers and rename your variable, but these do not give insight in how Swift functions work.

Swift automatically imports the `Swift` framework, where it defines its static functions. To use these functions, you usually do not need to specify that it's from the framework, but in cases like this, you should specify that you want to use the `abs` method from the `Swift` framework.

So after all the explanation, here's your code, which will work:

```
let value = -13
abs(value)

extension Int {
    var abs: Int {
        return Swift.abs(self)
    }
}

value.abs
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears just a call resolution problem. This will work:

```
let value = -13
abs(value)


extension Int {
    var abs1:Int {
        return abs(self)
    }
}

value.abs1
```

And this will work too:

```
extension Int {
    var abs:Int {
        return self < 0 ? -self : self
    }
}

value.abs
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are extending `Int` to add a variable named `abs` -- which is also the name of the function you are calling.

When you try to call the function `abs()` on the `Int`, it sees the variable `abs` that you created and it is confused because it thinks you are trying to return that variable and doesn't understand why you are sending it a parameter.

If you rename your variable to `absoluteValue` or anything else really, it should work.

```
let value = -13
abs(value)

extension Int {
var absoluteValue:Int {
        return abs(self)
    }
}

value.abs
```

**Update:** As others have stated, you can also solve the disambiguation of the use of `abs` by explicitly calling the function within the `Swift` framework. This should work just as well as the above solution.

```
let value = -13
abs(value)

extension Int {
var abs:Int {
        return Swift.abs(self)
    }
}

value.abs
```

Though, personally, I would still rename my new function to `absoluteValue` as in the first example so that its clear that you aren't calling the `Swift.abs()` when you use your `abs` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the direction of the original two answers (clash between global free function and the var I was defining), they have to be disambiguated. Rather than do my own inline implementation of abs or be forced to use a different name, I can properly scope the inside `abs()` using the `Swift` namespace.

```
extension Int {
    var absoluteValue:Int {
        return Swift.abs(self)
    }
}
```

This gives me the best of both worlds (IMO).